# Advanced object sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to work this out... Basically, I have an object with a structure similar to this:

```
results = {
  1 : {
    url    : '/',
    matches: {
      title : true,
      h1    : false,
      copy  : 2
    }
  },
  2 : {
    url    : '/?id=2',
    matches: {
      title : true,
      h1    : true,
      copy  : 0
    }
  },
  3 : {
    url    : '/id=3',
    matches: {
      title : false,
      h1    : false,
      copy  : 6
    }
  }
}
```

This is a result set from a custom search. I need the results to have weight for relevancy based on the matches within the objects. The results should be sorted like this:

1. Results having matches.title == true are the topmost results. Within this subset, matches.h1 being true carries the most weight (topmost), followed by the number of occurrences within the page copy (matches.copy).
2. Results having matches.h1 == true are to display next in the results view, sorted by the number of occurrences within the page copy (matches.copy).
3. Results with matches.title and matches.h1 both being false are sorted on matches.copy, in descending order.

Is this doable with the current object structure? Or do I need to split it up and cross-reference each subset? Gah! It's so early, and the coffee isn't working :(

---

**EDIT:**
Converted result set to an array of objects. New structure:

```
results = [
  { pageid: 1, url: '/', matches: { title: true, h1: false, copy: 2 } },
  { pageid: 2, url: '/?id=2', matches: { title: true, h1: true, copy: 0 } },
  { pageid: 3, url: '/?id=3', matches: { title: false, h1: false, copy: 6 } }
]
```

The sorting is still escaping me. I've done simple sorts before, but nothing to this degree. I came across LINQ, which seems promising, but I have no experience using it. Not sure if that's the right direction or not.

Comment: Make it an array A of objects, define this sort function sf, call A.sort(sf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using an array instead, which is designed for an ordered list.

You can use `.sort` and provide a custom search function: http://jsfiddle.net/uR4Jn/2/.

First try to move up an element having `.title === true` if the other element has `.title === false`. Otherwise, try to move up an element having `.h1 === true` if the other element has `.h1 === false`. Lastly, just sort on `.copy`. (And, move the item down in the first two cases if the opposite is true.)

```
var results = [
  {
    url    : '/',
    matches: {
      title : true,
      h1    : false,
      copy  : 2
    }
  },
  {
    url    : '/?id=2',
    matches: {
      title : true,
      h1    : true,
      copy  : 0
    }
  },
  {
    url    : '/id=3',
    matches: {
      title : false,
      h1    : false,
      copy  : 6
    }
  },
  {
    url    : '/id=3',
    matches: {
      title : false,
      h1    : false,
      copy  : 7
    }
  }
];

results = results.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.matches.title && !b.matches.title ? -1
         : (!a.matches.title && b.matches.title ? 1
         : (a.matches.h1 && !b.matches.h1 ? -1
         : (!a.matches.h1 && b.matches.h1 ? 1
         : b.matches.copy - a.matches.copy))));
});
```

Comment: I would add some parentheses to the return statement. Predecence of nested ternary operators differ in various languages and IMO it's better to not care about how it's in the current language but always use parens.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I actually like how JavaScript makes it possible to have nested conditional operators by starting each new case with `:` on a new line. But parens indeed make things clearer.

Comment: This looks like what I need... however, if I change the values in the first object, so that it has title: false, h1: false, and copy: 2, it still appears as the first item in the sorted result set. Any idea why?

Comment: @Steve: You're completely correct, I forgot to also move *down* the item for an opposite case. Please see my edit.

Comment: @pimvdb: You, sir, have just saved my sanity. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It's easily possible by calling `results.sort(function(a, b) { ... });` and then adding the proper logic to the callback: Return -1 if a<b, 1 if a>b, 0 if a==b.</strike>

Objects in JavaScript are not ordered. You need to convert it to an array if you want a specific order:

```
var resultList = [];
for(var elem in results) {
    resultList.push(results[elem]);
}
resultList.sort(function(a, b) {
    // perform your sorting
});
```

Since objects are passed by reference, you can still use `results[..]` to access one of the objects.